# Server side validation in Asp.net MVC4

Tags: dynamic, asp.net-mvc-4, validation

I am trying to build a website using ASP.Net MVC, where in I need to dynamically display **N** number of controls of different kind, and validate them.

My approach is to add them to a partial view using a html helper extension which is working well. But I am clueless on how to perform server side as well as client side validation for the same.

Please help me with suggestions on this.

Comment: Take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd901590%28v=VS.95%29.aspx - dataAnnotation validation attributes